# Jquery won't work on tidesdk

Tags: jquery, tidesdk

I'm starting to learn tidesdk, I want to try to include a some js functions written in jquery
but seams that doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).ready(function(){
            alert("ok");
            $('.p').css({"color":"red"});
        });     
    </script>
</head>
<body>


        <div class=".p" style="color:#000;background: #28A8D9;width:35%;height:350px;border:1px solid #000;">
            Just to try
        </div>
</body>
```

Is there anything wrong? I added jquery in the folder Resources.

p.s. tidesdk v1.3.1beta for windows

Comment: check errors thrown in browser console. Is there any jQuery dependent code in `app.js`?

Comment: no in app.js there's only tide code

Comment: never worked with tide but sounds like path is wrong ..try adding `Resources` directory to jQuery path

Comment: no is not a path problem.I tried without success.

Comment: assume that tide has some sort of javascript error console... look for errors

Answer (score 4):

the class on your DIV should be "p", not ".p"

```
<div class="p" ...
```

Comment: ahhaahh stupid problem i didn't notice that I leave the dot also in in the html tag ......

Comment: cool, glad that helped. do you mind marking this as the answer :)

Comment: @Francesco Please mark this as the answer. This is a syntax error that has no bearing on TideSDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing curly braces from .css()

like

```
$('.p').css("color", "red");
```

Comment: with the braces i can see the alert, without the braces it doesn't work

Comment: the problem seems to be in tide that dosen't parse jquery